# Selecting individual faces in maya using python

Tags: python, maya

Hey I am currently working on a tool in maya and have a need to select each face and measure the surface area of each. Does anyone here have a good idea on how to go about doing that? To be honest I am not sure where to start. Ideally I would like to keep all of the info within a dictionary so it can be easily iterated through. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object and iterate over each face and use polyInfo's faceToVertex to build up your list of vertices, then do your math.

http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/polyInfo.html

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [documentation of MItMeshPolygon](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_it_mesh_polygon.html). You can use it to iterate over each face of a mesh, and there's [a method](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_it_mesh_polygon.html#32ae9c59cee440dae99da3bc21675720) that computes the area of the face in different spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to capture your faces would be:

```
faces = [component for component in sel.f[:]]
```

I like to use list comprehensions and this way is more PyMEL like.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me as far as selecting faces

```
for i in range(0,connections):
    x = random.randrange(0,connections,1)
    print 'x = %d' %(x)
    cmd.select('polySphere_1.f[%d]' %(x), tgl = True,)
```